# Selecting data from 3 linked tables

Tags: sql, join, inner-join

I have three table `review_form_languages`, `review_form_translations` and `rate_params`.

1. `rate_params` -> id, label
2. `review_form_languages` -> id, name
3. `review_form_translations` -> id, rate_params_id, review_form_languages_id, text

On table `rate_params`, I would like to get the associated `review_form_translations.text` linked by `rate_params_id` for that specific `review_form_languages_id`.

Would anyone kindly assist?

Comment: Please post what you have already tried to help us suggest improvements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be looking for a simple JOIN. AFAIK, only two tables are involved :

```
SELECT rp.*, rft.text
FROM rate_params rp
INNER JOIN review_form_translations rft ON rft.rate_params_id = rp.id
WHERE rft.review_form_languages_id = ?
```

You may replace the `?` with the language id whose text you want to retrieve.